# Boyer Moore Implementation

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to implement Boyer Moore Algorithm for text searching and have come up with this implementation:

```
public class BoyerMooreStringSearching
{
    readonly Dictionary<char, LastIndexTable> _lastIndexTable = new Dictionary<char, LastIndexTable>();
    public string PatternToSearch;

    public List<int> GetStartingIndexsOfPatternInText(string textToSearchIn, string patternToSearch)
    {
        var list = new List<int>();
        PatternToSearch = patternToSearch;
        if (patternToSearch != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToSearchIn))
        {
            // Update Last Index Table
            UpdateLastIndexTable(patternToSearch);
            PatternToSearch = patternToSearch;

            var j = patternToSearch.Length - 1;

            // Main loop to iterate over whole text
            while (j <= textToSearchIn.Length - 1)
            {
                var lastCharOfPattern = patternToSearch[patternToSearch.Length - 1];

                if (textToSearchIn[j] != lastCharOfPattern)
                {
                    //  Heuristic 1 
                    // If Last Char is not matched with the Last char in pattern and char is not present in the pattern
                    // Then advance pointer 'j' to the length of the pattern in textToSearch.
                    if (!_lastIndexTable.ContainsKey(textToSearchIn[j]))
                    {
                        j += patternToSearch.Length - 1;
                    }

                    // Heuristic 2 
                    // Consult the lastIndex table to get the last index of current char in textToSearch
                    // and advance pointer 'j' to the last index in textToSearch.
                    if (j <= textToSearchIn.Length - 1 && _lastIndexTable.ContainsKey(textToSearchIn[j]))
                    {
                        var tempObj = _lastIndexTable[textToSearchIn[j]];
                        if (tempObj != null) j += tempObj.LastIndex;
                    }
                }

                int k = patternToSearch.Length - 1;
                int u = j;
                if (j <= textToSearchIn.Length - 1)
                {
                    while (k >= 0)
                    {
                        // Heuristic (3a) 
                        // If Last Char is  matched with the Last char in pattern then back track in the text and pattern till 
                        // either you got a complete match or a   mismatched charecter.
                        // Once you got the mismatched char and mismatched char is not present in the pattern then
                        // advance j to the index of mismatched  charecter in the pattern 
                        if (textToSearchIn[u] == patternToSearch[k])
                        {
                            if (k == 0 && textToSearchIn[u] == patternToSearch[k])
                            {
                                list.Add(u);
                                j += patternToSearch.Length - 1;
                            }
                            u--;
                            k--;
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (!_lastIndexTable.ContainsKey(textToSearchIn[u]))
                        {
                            // Heuristic (3b) 
                            // If Last Char is  matched with the Last char in pattern then back track in the text  till 
                            // either you got a complete match or a   mismatched charecter.
                            // Once you got the mismatched char and mismatched char is not present in the pattern then
                            // advance j to the index of mismatched  charecter in the pattern  plus the number to char which matched.
                            j += k + (j - u);
                            break;
                        }

                        k--;
                    }
                }

                j++;
            }

        }
        if (!list.Any())
            list.Add(-1);

        return list;
    }

    private void UpdateLastIndexTable(string patternToSearch)
    {
        _lastIndexTable.Clear();
        var i = patternToSearch.Length - 1;
        foreach (var charToSeach in patternToSearch)
        {
            if (_lastIndexTable.ContainsKey(charToSeach))
            {
                _lastIndexTable[charToSeach].LastIndex = i;
            }
            else
            {
                _lastIndexTable.Add(charToSeach, new LastIndexTable
                {
                    CharSearched = charToSeach,
                    LastIndex = i
                });
            }
            i--;
        }
    }
}

public class LastIndexTable
{
    public char CharSearched { get; set; }

    public int LastIndex { get; set; }
}
```

Please can you review and provide feedback?

Comment: The standard way to deal with indices is `v < element.Length`, which is mostly to help prevent off-by-one (fencepost) errors.  Dijkstra has [some notes on this](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).

Answer (score 4):

I have checked your code and there are some things which I would change:

- Create an interface, say, `IStringSearcher` with one method `List<int> GetStartingIndexsOfPatternInText(string textToSearchIn, string patternToSearch)`. That will help you to change string searching algorithm implementation without client code changes.
- `GetStartingIndexsOfPatternInText` method name seems to be a bit long and personally I would change the name.
- I would either make `BoyerMooreStringSearching` class as **read-only** or **utility** class. That change will be very beneficial if you think about multi-thread applications.

  - **read-only** - `text to search` and `pattern to search` would be provided in the class constructor and could not be changed
  - *OR* **utility class**. In that case `BoyerMooreStringSearching` class and `GetStartingIndexsOfPatternInText` method would be static.
- I would throw some exception if provided strings do not meet your requirements (you should document your requirements in the class documentation) e.g.

  - if one of the strings is null or empty or
  - if `pattern string` is longer than `text to search`
- `PatternToSearch = patternToSearch;` statement is used twice in your code: one before and another after the first `if` statement.
- `public string PatternToSearch;` I do not think it needs to be there as you do not read it.
- I see that you use lots of variables like `k`, `u`, `j` etc. I think you should use more meaningful names. After couple of months the code will be more readable for you when you forgot what you had written.

I hope that will help.